# I can't see AVD manager window in android studio 0.4.0

Tags: android-studio, android-virtual-device

I am using windows 8,android studio 0.4.0 jdk 7_45 and jre7 installed. JAVA_HOME and JAVA variables are also set in Environment Path Variables.

When I click on tools-> android->avd manager , it shows nothing (not even error anywhere) . Nothing at all happens.

What should i do? I guess this version is not very stable.

Comment: Anything interesting in `idea.log` (Help menu > Show log)?

Comment: Go to your Android SDK directory and try to run AVD Manager from there and update if it is working fine from there.

Comment: @pyus13 when i try to run C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk\tools\lib\AVDManager.exe it says "Failed to execute tools\android.bat: The system cannot find the file specified." and thx for correcting the version mentioned in question :)

Comment: @ScottBarta after a click on AVD manager through the ide my log file gets filled with this https://docs.google.com/document/d/1li-whoGdSYU_7pV-o5PE1j52M7CdAKxCGCjCjW3_yRY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: don't run it from `\tools\lib\AVDManager.exe ` it will always give the error. Try to run from sdk\AVDManager.exe itself and let me know, if its not there copy and paste it from `\tools\lib\AVDManager.exe`.

Comment: @pyus13 thx buddy, i copied the \tools\lib\AVDManager.exe to sdk folder and now it is running as standalone and from the ide too! thx a lot.

Comment: @SunilSharma I put it on answer accept it to help others.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It Seems your AVD Manager is missing from root SDK directory please follow the Steps

```
1. Go to sdk\tools\lib\ and copy AVDManager.exe
2. Paste it to root of your sdk Directory.
```

Now you have sdk\AVD Manager.exe

Now try to run it.

Comment: I can't find it in sdk\tools\lib\

Answer (score 6):

Check the permission for your Android folder.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android
```

I fixed the same issue by right-clicking on the Android directory then

**Properties->Security** then selected the user name and ticked **Full control** then hit **OK**

Comment: yah this permission thing was creating problem for me

Answer (score 2):

If all else fails run as Administrator - this worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, you need to go to android directory at first time.
Try to run Android studio in projectName/android folder. Then button AVD Manager must be active.

Answer (score 0):

Run monitor.bat from android/sdk/tools, It open Android Device monitor.
From Window menu select AVD manager and also sdk manager.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to access AVD without the help of Android studio.

AVD can be found:

```
C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\AVD Manager.exe
```

You will need to run this as administrator by right clicking and clicking 'Run as Administrator'

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem.

Check you don't have any errors on the bottom of android studio. I got one with sdk build. If you got the same click on the link in error log.

Next go to file -> settings -> Appearance&Behavior -> Menus and Toolbars. 
Roll up Main menu -> Tools. 
Choose Android. 
Click on 'Apply' button and 'OK'. 
Wait for a while (gradel progressbar on the bottom).

I hope that I solve your problem.